# poner comas entre los resultados de MySQL

Tags: php

Tengo un registro de permisos separado de la siguiente manera:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="icheck-primary d-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" name="Registrar" value="1" id="checkboxPrimary1"> <label for="checkboxPrimary1">Registrar</label>
    </div>
    <div class="icheck-primary d-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" name="Editar" value="1"  id="checkboxPrimary2"> <label for="checkboxPrimary2">Editar</label>
    </div>
     <div class="icheck-primary d-inline">
         <input type="checkbox" name="Eliminar" value="1" id="checkboxPrimary3"> <label for="checkboxPrimary3">Eliminar</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Para enumerar los permisos, hago lo siguiente:

```
$registrar  = ($pd->admin_create == 1)?'Registrar':"";
$editar     = ($pd->admin_edit == 1)?'Editar':"";
$eliminar   = ($pd->admin_delete == 1)?'Eliminar':"";
$array = array($registrar,$editar,$eliminar);
$permisos = implode(',',$array);
```

Cuando el valor es cero, no debería aparecer. Por ejemplo. Si un administrador solo puede registrarse y eliminar, me gustaría que apareciera de la siguiente manera:

> **Registrar,Eliminar**

Pero está regresando así:

> **Registrar,,Eliminar**

¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto? Perdona mi español.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usa [array_filter()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php), que sin usar callback, puede quitar los valores `false` de un array:

```php
> $a = 'Uno';
> $b = '';
> $c = 'Tres';
> echo implode(',', array_filter([$a, $b, $c]));
Uno,Tres
```

Comment: ¡Trabajado! Muchas gracias aeportugal.